# Sound disappearing in Flash 9 on non-IE browsers

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

I'm working on a site (http://easy2speak.com) with about 10 flash SWFs on each page. Each of the SWFs are playing back a sound when clicked. Loading the sound, and playing it without any latency works fine, but in Flash player version 9 on all major browsers except IE, the sound suddenly drops out. It usually works for the first 10-20 clicks, then the SWFs will be totally silent until the next machine/browser restart.

In Flash player v10 (exactly the same code) it works perfectly. It also works perfectly in Flash player v9 in Internet Explorer.

Any ideas ?

Would love to hear some brain-storming on how to get around this problem as well, as I start to suspect there is no easy fix I can do in code.

By the way, the site has 1000+ sounds in MP3, so any solution can't involve embedding the sounds.

Comment: Wow. That sounds like a nasty one. I hope SO can help out, but I wouldn't hold my breath. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the loading of the sound is the cause of your problem. Assuming Flash loads the files from the same url, maybe non IE browsers can't handle multiple requests of the same mp3 file in one browser session.

You can try changing the load object url in your as3 code to a unique url even if the same file is loaded so that upon every new request the browser thinks it's a new file and wont let you down.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code looks like but usually cases where something works and then stops working after several repeats, means you are not clearing objects from memory after they are not needed. So just make sure you are removing event listeners of unused objects, removing the objects and then setting them to null.

-JB